# Elasticsearch index design - Free form fields, and text vs flattened query limitations and concerns

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am designing my first elastic search index.  My Document has 2 fields that are free form to the user, either string / number / bool / nested JSON object.  After researching, as far as i can see there is no good way to index this as full fields in ES.  Even if I can split the indices in way to avoid mapping explosion, there is no way to ensure one doc wont have a field N levels deep named "status" thats an object, and a second doc wouldn't have the same field name at the same level thats a concrete type.  ES doesn't seem to deal with this well.  Even if this isn't the greatest for ES, this is none the less, what I have as far as a data model.

To that end, after researching, I've come to the conclusion I need to either:

Stringify the fields before insertion, and insert as txt with the field mapping:

```
"payload" : {
  "type" : "text",
    "fields" : {
      "keyword" : {
        "type" : "keyword",
        "ignore_above" : 256
      }
   }
}
```

or

use the flattened type here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html

The flattened data type looks like it is along the lines of what I need.  However, as the docs show there are some query limitations.  I am concerned about it because I cant get a clear picture of the Query limitations and other concerns with flattened vs a txt field, and admittedly I have limited experience with ES.

My questions:

1. Does anyone have relevant experience comparing a text to a flattened field of similar data in a real production scenario, and could you provide some insight around pros / cons of each?
2. Am I missing any other obvious options for handling free formed fields as described, while maintaining as much search capability as possible?

Some additional info:

My elastic search is 7.4 at the moment, in case that impacts any response.
Document might look something like this:

```
{
   "id": “UUID”,
   "name": “Document-Name-1”,
   "time": 1583759162707,
   "source": “Sender”,
   “data": <free form schema, tied to name, could be any concrete type or object of arbitrary depth and field config> 
}
```

I considered having a different index per "name" field, but I will have an unknown number of names and schemas, so that would entail searching across 100s of indices over time.

I don't know exactly what type of queries I will need at this point, except the contents of the "data" field needs to be searchable.  That drove the question to be more along the lines of understanding which is most flexible between text and flattened type when querying.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: adding how your sample doc and what types of searches(some sample queries) would help us to give better recommendations

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja - I added some relevant info, but I don't know much about the needed queries at this time.

Comment: It's very hard to provide a recommendation without knowing much about the underlying use case. If you decide to store data inside Elasticsearch it's usually because you have a search need. If you don't know what queries you need right now, I'd suggest to think very hard about them before going any further. Anything you do in Elasticsearch MUST be driven by your search needs, any other way means Elasticsearch is probably not the tool you need. Since your question has more than a year now, maybe you've gotten a bit further in your exploration, so feel free to share anything new.

Comment: @Val, Your answer is spot on.  A year later I have a much better sense of data, and the kind of things I want to do with the data.  I cant even say I know the queries, because elastic isn't suited for some of it.  Aggregations / stats are a small part of my use case, and Im investigating other options that are better suited for my document search and data queries.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the feedback, much appreciated!